# How do I use a variable containing a filename with spaces in a bash script?

Tags: bash, filenames, spaces, cp

I have a simple bash script running on OS X that removes specific files and directories and copies new ones in their place.  One Mac .app directory contains a space, and when I run the script there is a "No such file or directory" error.

Here is the relevant code.  A good amount has been cut out, so simply hard coding these differently isn't possible (the variables must be broken up as they are):

```
CP="cp -Rf"

INSTALL_DIR="/Applications/"

APP="The App.app"

NEWAPP="$HOME/Downloads/The App.app"

$CP "$NEWAPP " "$INSTALL_DIR$NEWAPP"
```

I've tried escaping `The\ App.app` with no luck, as well as trying single quoting, double quoting, and double escaping, but nothing has worked.  I imagine there is a simple way to do this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't you want `"$NEWAPP "` without the trailing space?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an extra space there, it's simply

"$NEWAPP"

Comment: Wow, that was an artifact from a previous change, and I didn't notice.  Changing this definitely fixed some of the problems, as well as emergence's comment below.  Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score -2):

enclose the whole final line in quotes:

```
"$CP $NEWAPP $INSTALL_DIR$NEWAPP"
```

it's unnecessary to keep opening and closing the quotes here, and the $CP must be contained in quotes as CP has a space in it.

Comment: nope. that actually tries to execute a command whose name is all the variables substituted. also, cp in quotes will try to execute the command whose name is "cp -Rf". everything in quotes is interpreted as one element. first element is the name of the command, the rest are the parameters.

Comment: you're right, sorry. the final $NEWAPP should be $APP however or it's going to try and append $HOME/Downloads again.

Comment: emergence -- your comment is correct; I didn't notice that I had written NEWAPP vs APP.  This, combined with removing the space, seemed to wrok fine.  Two stupid errors working together.  Thanks for the help.